# How to properly initialize a stochastic vector?

Tags: probability, distributions

I'd like create a stochastic vector $$\mathbf{v} = (v_1, \dots, v_n)$$ of length $n$, so that its elements are assigned weights according to a given parameter ("entropy"): the weights are either uniformly distributed with $p_i = 1/n$, or there's a "bump" at a particular position and other elements decay to 0 quickly -- with the speed specified by the parameter.

In my head, it should look similar to Poisson's pdf:

[image: pois_pdf]

Comment: Possible answers to this question are infinitely numerous and almost completely arbitrary.  Could you perhaps tell us what you are trying to accomplish with this random vector?

Comment: @whuber, oh, it's Hidden Markov Model's transition / observation matrices $A,B$ and a-priori probability vector $\pi$.

Comment: Could you please give us some information to deduce what the probability distribution of $\mathbf{v}$ ought to be?

Comment: @whuber, that's the point -- it should vary according to the parameter ("entropy", roughly), that controls the degree of non-uniformness. The end goal is to test Viterbi algorithm with various randomly initialized matrices. Seems like it works best when matrices are initialized non-uniformly with most of the entries being close to 0.